# Ruby / yaml delete element from assoc array

Tags: arrays, ruby, yaml, associative-array

Hey guys i have array in yml

```
 menu:
      primary:
        name: General menu
        -
          text: Home
          addr: index.html
        -
          text: Contact
          addr: contact.html
```

and i have menu (i created variable menu, because when i use just print ... element['text']... i get something like var_dump from php no only text "Start") i want to delete 'name' element before foreach but it's doesn't work:

```
name = $data['name'][name]['name'] # i need this variable later
$data['menu'][name].delete('name') # it doesnt work
menu = "<ul>"
$data['menu'][name].each do |element|
    menu << "<li><a href=\"#{element['addr']}\">#{element['text']}</a></li>"
end
menu << "</ul>"
print menu
```

my error is

> did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at...

so function delete doesnt work here, my question is, how can i delete "name" element from this array? And why
`print "<li><a href=\"#{element['addr']}\">#{element['text']}</a></li>"` doesnt work?
Thanks for help :-)

Comment: Ou i found a big mistake, my var name is "name" and this overwrite my previous variable: name = 'primary'. This is a silly mistake. but still i don't know why doesn't work simply print "<li>[...]</li>" and i must use variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your YAML is not valid because the array has to be associated with a key. You may want to use something like:

```
menu:
  primary:
    name: General menu
    items:
      -
        text: Home
        addr: index.html
      -
        text: Contact
        addr: contact.html
```

Also, please get rid of PHP practice of prefixing variables with $. In ruby this makes variables global and they should be avoided as much as possible.

Following illustrates the operation you intended:

```
data = YAML.load <<YAML
menu:
  primary:
    name: General menu
    items:
      -
        text: Home
        addr: index.html
      -
        text: Contact
        addr: contact.html
YAML
```

---

```
=> data 
{"menu"=>{"primary"=>{"name"=>"General menu", "items"=>[{"text"=>"Home", "addr"=>"index.html"}, {"text"=>"Contact", "addr"=>"contact.html"}]}}}
=> data['menu']['primary'].delete('name')
"General menu"
=> data
{"menu"=>{"primary"=>{"items"=>[{"text"=>"Home", "addr"=>"index.html"}, {"text"=>"Contact", "addr"=>"contact.html"}]}}}
```

Your HTML builder should also work as follows:

```
menu = "<ul>"
data['menu']['primary']['items'].each do |element|
  menu << "<li><a href=\"#{element['addr']}\">#{element['text']}</a></li>"
end
menu << "</ul>"
```

Comment: Please read my comment in first post. I know that prefix $ make global variable, and this is global variable and this code is in a function. I know that, i overwrite my previous variable "name" and that why it's doesnt work. Thanks for help :) And do you know how can i print element without use variable?